# Layer on node.js to return results based on lower latency API methods

Tags: javascript, node.js, api-design

I am looking to write a layer in node.js where I can divert a sample traffic to two different APIs and return the results whenever any of the API send results to layer. 
Both of APIs return same results, I just want to do A/B test APIs simultaneously so that faster one wins.

Comment: use something like Promise.race()

Comment: Thanks @dandavis, should solve my problem.